# Please merge my two data.SE accounts

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm told that a meta post is the way to go to get SEDE accounts merged, so here we are:

- [Newer account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/22834/artofcode22835)
- [Older account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/15030/artofcode)

are both mine; could I have them merged into the older account?

Comment: @Oded just closed SQL Server Management Studio, come back another time ;)

Comment: Have you tried '[contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)' form ? It has a option to specify merging of profiles. `Topic =` **I need to merge user profiles**

Comment: @Raju That's for main sites, not SEDE. I've asked an SE developer how to get SEDE accounts merged, and they indicated I should create a meta post.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, oohhh. Fine then. But, meta post is a bad idea. They should add an option in existing forms/menus.