# In data.stackexchange a login action for an existing account created a new user instead

Tags: bug, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I've been using data.exchange for a few months now, and I've always used the "Log in using Google" to sign in, but today, I used "Login using Stack Exchange" for the same email.

This option created a new user account for me. Then I thought maybe it didn't connect them to each other, so I logged out. But when I tried to log in using Google, I was logged in to my second account and basically I lost the way I could log in to my original one.

This is my first account: [Profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/31038/moradnejad)

This is the second account: [Profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/31803/jon-doe31804)

In short, it shouldn't have created a second user. I still need to be able to log in as my first user.

Comment: It is a known failure condition and happened before. It is not "Serious" it is at best inconvenient when you're impacted by this.

Comment: So I lost my access to my user and it's not serious. Huh!

Comment: Why do we even report bugs if no one fixes them? @rene

Comment: SEDE is open source so someone needs to dedicate their free time to fix this. On top of that, this specific bug is notoriously hard to reproduce or diagnose as it involves multiple moving parts.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277651/please-merge-my-two-data-se-accounts and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256399/data-explorer-created-a-new-account-issuing-an-account-merge-request-resulted-i and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277611/data-explorer-site-created-new-jon-doe-account-instead-of-logging-me-to-the-old

Comment: Then will they merge my two accounts? @rene

Comment: Based on the feedback on the other incidents you might have some luck, or not, when you contact support.

Comment: @rene, you missed one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197828/please-merge-sede-accounts-normal-options-unavailable. And:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160143/make-it-possible-to-merge-user-accounts-in-data-explorer.